Relative divisibility of derived subgroup of free group
Let $F$ be a free group (possibly on an infinite set) and let $[F,F]$ denote its derived subgroup.
Can there be a $w \in F \setminus [F,F]$ and an $n>0$ such that $w^n \in [F,F]$?

What do you think?

Seeing no obstruction to the existence of such words, I would expect that there should be examples. But that's quite a guess.

Hint: Do you know what is the quotient $F/[F,F]$ isomorphic to?

@Mark: thanks, indeed! Feel free to post the hint as an answer.

No. If $F$ has rank $\kappa$ (any cardinal, possibly infinite), then quotient $F/[F,F]$ is the free abelian group of rank $\kappa$. As free abelian groups are torsion free, if $w^n\in [F,F]$, then $w[F,F]$ is torsion in a free abelian group, so either $n=0$ or $w\in [F,F]$.
